# A good substitution to prove $\frac{f(b)-f(a)-(b-a)f'(a)}{g(b)-g(a)-(b-a)g'(a)}=\frac{f''(c)}{g''(c)}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ satisfy the hypothesis of mean value theorem, then prove that

> $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)-(b-a)f'(a)}{g(b)-g(a)-(b-a)g'(a)}=\frac{f''(c)}{g''(c)}$$

where $g''(c)\neq 0$. I have tried various things like Cauchy **MVT** with $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$, substituting $h(x)=\dfrac{1}{g'(x)}$ ,$h(x)=f'(x)+\dfrac{a}{g'(x)}$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$, but it didn't lead anywhere. Any help will be appreciated. Please note that I am allowed to use only Cauchy's **MVT**, **LMVT** and **Rolle**'s theorem.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993286/mean-value-theorem-to-second-derivative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$ k=\frac{f(b)-f(a)-(b-a)f'(a)}{g(b)-g(a)-(b-a)g'(a)}. $$
Define
$$ F(x)=f(x)-f(a)-(x-a)f'(a)-k[g(x)-g(a)-(x-a)g'(a)]. $$
Then
$$ F(a)=0, F(b)=0. $$
By Rolle's Theorem, there is $\xi\in(a,b)$ such that $F'(\xi)=0$, namely
$$ f'(\xi)-f'(a)-k[g'(\xi)-g'(a)]=0$$
from which one has
$$ k=\frac{f'(\xi)-f'(a)}{g'(\xi)-g'(a)}.$$
By Cauchy's Theorem, there is $c\in(a,\xi)$ such that
$$ k=\frac{f'(\xi)-f'(a)}{g'(\xi)-g'(a)}=\frac{f''(c)}{g''(c)}.$$
Done.